# SharePoint contact's custom fields are not showing up in Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, contacts

I have created one Contact list in SharePoint Online with some custom fields. The list is having 2000 contacts. Now I want to connect my SharePoint contact list to Outlook.

**What I did is :**
I have connected my SharePoint contact list to outlook using "`Connect to outlook`" option and all contacts are showing up in Outlook. But,

**The problem is :**
The custom fields are not displaying when I open any contact in Outlook.

Is there any workaround for getting custom fields in Outlook? If there are any third party tool available then please suggest.